# Why is my MySQL database crashing on Windows IIS 6 with VMWARE error 1784

Tags: mysql, windows, iis-6, vmware, windows-server-2003

This is the errormessage from the MySQL error-log

> 130323  1:13:49  InnoDB: Operating system error number 1784 in a file operation.
>
> InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/  refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
>
> InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
>
> InnoDB: File operation call: 'Windows aio'.
>
> InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
>
> 130323  1:14:51 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 130323  1:14:51 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 130323  1:14:51 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 130323  1:14:51 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 130323  1:14:51 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 339.0M
>
> 130323  1:14:51 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 130323  1:14:51 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 6667918676
>
> 130323  1:14:51  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
>
> InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
> (...)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a MySQL-server in a hosted area (virtualisation), there is a Sync Driver (process: LGTO Sync) that quiescies the hard drive before VMWare takes a snapshot. This process stops all I/O requests to the drive and makes MySQL crash with the error code mentioned. Solution: disable the sync driver on database servers.

To disable the SYNC driver:
- In the Windows Device Manager, click View > Show hidden devices.
- Expand Non-Plug and Play Drivers.
- Right-click Sync Driver and click Disable.
- Click Yes twice to disable the device and restart the computer.

Check also 'don't load on restart', otherwise you have the same problem again at a reboot...

Comment: boy you answered your question the same second you asked it. you are good !

Comment: after 4 weeks searching for the problem, maybe I can help somebody with it...;)

Comment: ok then, i will upvote ! but just saying i am not sure if this is the way it is supposed to work here :>